# geoTIFF File conversion in QGIS - creation parameters not defined

Tags: qgis

I want to convert a geoTIFF file into ESRI Grid Format (Arcinfo Binary Grid)using QGIS --Raster--Conversion---translate tool but I get a error message saying "creation parameters not defined". What is this and how to proceed next?

Comment: can you copy the content of the command line box and paste it into your question?

Comment: I had not used command line but doing it through GUI interface of QGIS 2.14.1

Comment: Yes, but the GUI writes the command in a textbox before you hit `OK`. The content of that box might lead to the reason of the error.

Comment: The error is ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format. And the command is gdal_translate -of AIG M:/CCSM4_2.5_2070/CCSM4_2-5_2070_2.6tif/cc26bi701.tif M:/CCSM4_2.5_2070/CCSM4_2-5_2070_2.6tif/cc26bi701

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html:

```
AIG -- Arc/Info Binary Grid

Supported by GDAL for read access.
```

http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html and `Settings -> Options -> GDAL` tell you the same.

So you are out of luck trying to write to that format. If you need to, you have to do the conversion with ESRI software.